# Excel formula - Get the sum of each variable every 6 days

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, sum, sumifs

[image]

I have the following dataset where I want to get the sum of each variable every 6 days. I can get the total sum of every 6 days using

```
=SUM(OFFSET($A$2,,(COLUMNS($A$5:A5)-1)*6,,6))
```

And I can get the total sum of each variable using

```
=SUMIF(A1:S1,A1,A2:S2)
```

But I cant get the total sum of each variable within the block of 6 days. It won't increment when I drag the formula.
So the results should be

```
      First batch      Second batch         Third batch
A      B       C      A      B       C      A      B       C
2      2       2      4      4       4      6      6       6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((1:1=A6)*2:2*(COLUMN(1:1)>(INT((COLUMN()-1)/3)*6))*(COLUMN(1:1)<=(INT((COLUMN()-1)/3+1)*6)))
```

[image]

**Edit:**

To shift the column by five position, you will need to change the following parameters in the formula:

1. Full row range change to exact range, i.e. `1:1` to e.g. `$F$1:$W$1`
2. Change `COLUMN()-1` to `COLUMN()-3`

If you also want to change the number of columns to be summed, additionally replace the factor of `6` with a `7-1` for seven columns or `36-30` for thirty-six columns.

So formulas looks like:

batch of 6 cols

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($F$1:$W$1=F6)*$F$2:$W$2*(COLUMN($F$1:$W$1)>=((INT((COLUMN()-3)/3))*6))*(COLUMN($F$1:$W$1)<((INT((COLUMN()-3)/3+1))*6)))
```

batch of 7 cols

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($F$1:$Z$1=F6)*$F$2:$Z$2*(COLUMN($F$1:$Z$1)>=((INT((COLUMN()-3)/3))*7-1))*(COLUMN($F$1:$Z$1)<((INT((COLUMN()-3)/3+1))*7-1)))
```

batch of 36 cols

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($F$1:$WW$1=F6)*$F$2:$WW$2*(COLUMN($F$1:$WW$1)>=((INT((COLUMN()-3)/3))*36-30))*(COLUMN($F$1:$WW$1)<((INT((COLUMN()-3)/3+1))*36-30)))
```

Comment: Wow. That worked. Can you please break down the formula? I might need to adjust it from every 6 column to every 7 column - but I'm not sure how it works!

Comment: And there might also be some spreadsheets that I would need to get sum of every variable for every 36th column :)

Comment: Also, I noticed that the numbers change if I decide to move my data to start from F1. I needed to add some row names so I had to move my data 5 columns.

Comment: @cms72 To change the number of columns that are summed, it is necessary to change the factor of ```6``` to the appropriate - to sum up ```7``` columns, it will be ```7```, to sum up ```36``` columns, it will be ```36```. Shifting the columns will be more complicated. Will both the source  data range and the result range be shifted by 5 columns?

Comment: Hi @basic - thanks for the reply! Yes, both the source datarange and result range will be shifted as well by 5 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a really, really, really complex formula that can be dragged right, I suggest you add a row to the data at the top that identifies the batch number. Then you can use that batch number as an additional parameter in the Sumifs(). you can hide the rows with the batch numbers if they upset your spreadsheet design.

```
=SUMIFS(3:3,1:1,A16,2:2,A17)
```

[image]

This is far easier than creating a formula that dynamically adjusts references in tiered steps of three and six.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Hi teylyn, thank you for the reply. How do I make it work on merged "batch" cells? I have about 52 different batches with at least 6 variables in each batch.

Comment: Don't. Use. Merged. Cells. There's not enough aspirin to help with the pain caused by merged cells. Use a row where each cell has the correct batch number. If you don't want to see that row, hide it. Use a decoration row with merged cells for labelling, if you want, but merged cells are useless for calculations. That kind of setup is not complex to make and easy to maintain, compared to the complex formula in the other answer.